# apt broken with install or remove anything

Tags: apt, updates

hi I have some problem with apt ;-;

```
Unpacking libgles-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h', which is also in package libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgles-dev_1.3.2-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can't install pacakge so i can't do apt --fix-broken install
I have try so many method but 0 have work
don't tell me to check on internet I already check

Comment: no this doesnt answer to me

Comment: Your version of the `libgles2-mesa-dev` package is not provided by any supported release of Ubuntu. Uninstall that package. If you must have that package, install the Ubuntu version. Then installing `libgles-dev` will work.